# Run scheduler on authenticated api

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, cron, google-cloud-scheduler

I wanna run scheduled job on one of my api. All of my api are authenticated that means they expect a Bearer token as Authorization, which is dynamically generated by firebase auth everytime we hit the api from the app. Suppose I wanna run `app.get("/hi", fn(req, res))`, lets say 1 times a day. How to run it?

Currently I tried using google cloud scheduler and google cron jobs. But the problem with both of them is that they cannot carry dynamic headers with them. Is there a way I can generate dynamic bearer auth token and send it as header in the cron job request. Or can service account be useful here? or is there any alternative other than cron jobs and google cloud scheduler?

Comment: Cloud Scheduler can generate dynamic access token or identity token to access APIs. If you need another type of dynamic tokens, you must create a "proxy layer" with a Cloud Functions or a Cloud Run that add this extra authentication header.

Comment: Hey, I have deployed my app on app engine. Can you please share docs where Cloud Scheduler can generate dynamic access token or identity token to access APIs. Can my firebase auth be unauthenticated using access token??? I am a beginner so please be patient. :)

Comment: Ok, your app in on AppEngine. Do you have activated any security layer? Like IAP in front of AppEngine? Can you detail more your configuration to be able to reproduce it on our side?

Comment: Ok, so any request made on our api by the android app is firstly sent to authenticate function using middleware, that function then checks for the bearer token [we use firebase auth for authentication] and if evrythings good then sent the req to desired api. So while sending request from cron jobs I cannot attach dynamic headers. Dynamic headers becuase the andriod app generates token each time which is only valid for like 1 hr.

Comment: Understood and indeed, you can't use directly this function. Firebase auth is designed for end users and not for automation. You must have 2 different entry point, one checking the identity coming from android, the other coming from the cloud. Then a 3rd function that perform the business processing. (you have to separate the authZ layer to the processing layer)

Comment: Ahh! I see. Thanks bro @guillaumeblaquiere. Any tips as how can I check and differentiate entry from app and scheduler?

Comment: Differentiate the entry in your 3rd functions, your business functions? If so, add a header when you call the 3rd functions